# Hide child DIV on generating parent div Dynamically through live in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a button(OnClick) i am creating markup with several divs inside by using LIVE in Jquery.  I am using

```
 parentLi.show().trigger("updatelayout");
```

to update the markup. Similarly, i can create multiple parent div with multiple child DIV inside it.

I want to hide a particular child DIV and display rest of the DIV's. The below line of code is hiding all the DIV's, but i want to hide recently generated/generating DIV.

```
$(".dropdown").css("display","none");
```

the above code is hiding all the DIV's which has **.dropdown** class.

I want to hide only currently generating markup which is having (.dropdown) class.

Help Required!

My Code:

```
$("#btnAddEmp").live("click", function(){   


    var parentLi = $(this).parents("li").prev(); //Cloning Markup
    var cloneLi = parentLi.clone().val("");    
    var maxSeqNbr = parseInt($("#MAX_SEQ_NBR").val()) + 1;
    var newLi = parentLi.after(cloneLi);

    newLi.find("#One").attr("name","eName" + "$" + maxSeqNbr);
    newLi.find("#two").attr("name","eNumber" + "$" + maxSeqNbr);
    newLi.find("#three").attr("name","eEmail" + "$" + maxSeqNbr);       
    newLi.find("#four").attr("name","eType" + "$" + maxSeqNbr);
    newLi.find("#five").attr("name","eDOB" + "$" + maxSeqNbr); //This code will increment the employee name attribute with $1, $2...
    newLi.trigger("updatelayout");

    $(".empDOB").css("display","none"); //want to hide the eDOB Field and label surrounded by a div with a class name .empDOB

        parentLi.show().trigger("updatelayout");

        $("#MAX_SEQ_NBR").val(maxSeqNbr);
});
```

Comment: Could you please show a full code sample in your question. Also note that `live()` is deprecated. You should be using `on()` instead

Comment: `$(".dropdown:last").css("display","none");`

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes, It Was Awesome. Helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: that's nice. I am not sure if you should keep the question or delete. because the question should be how to get the last element and it would be easily found by trying to google that.